# Plotly python axix ticker format problems with epoch time that has milliseconds

Tags: python, plotly

my x axis values are in epoch time with milliseconds. When I try to set the xaxis ticker to a more readable format such as:

```py
fig.update_layout(
            xaxis = {'type': 'date','tickformat': '%H:%M:%S'},
            )
```

The date doesn't come through correctly as expected. The year, day, hour, are all incorrect. I cannot find the proper way to do this with plotly python. If someone could provide an example that would be great.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: That is how you format tick labels in plotly python.

Comment: I meant a sample of your original `df`.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had much luck with millisecond timestamps either. One solution could be to pre-format before going to Plotly. This slows down performance, but there *are* certain formats Plotly recognizes.

Not assuming you are using pandas as your inputs, but you can build the format like so:

```
        df2[xaxis_name] = pd.to_datetime(df[xaxis_name], unit='ms').dt.date
```

https://plotly.com/python/time-series/

Then you can further refine it with:

https://plotly.com/python/reference/#layout-xaxis-tickformat

Such as:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
           tickformat = "%b-%Y"
        )
```

Worked for me.

[image]

> Plotly auto-sets the axis type to a date format when the corresponding
> data are either ISO-formatted date strings or if they're a date pandas
> column or datetime NumPy array.